# Custom membership provider with repository injection and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am about to start on a new project. I would like to use custom membership, with repository injection and Entity Framework (database first).

I found lot of articles on each of the above three, but not all three. Since I haven't used any of these before, I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around how to implement it.

Can someone please point me to any article? Or any simple (pseudo) code sample on how the classes are organized, how they interact with each other, etc? Or just an explanation?

Thanks

Comment: If you mean dependency injection when you say injection, then I would stay far away from using DI in a membership provider.  It's possible to do it, but it's difficult, and a huge hack.. and it's just ugly.. it also largely defeats the purpose, since Membership is a static instance, making it all but impossible to test properly.  I'd use ASP.NET Identity instead if you're going new, but that will require Visual Studio 2012 or 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experience, [Asp.net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) have almost  everything for Membership, even you can extend it using Code-first Migrations the way you want.

Here is the sample code which demonstrates *Repository Pattern*, *Dependency Injection* & EF Database-First paradigm,

```
***DATA LAYER***

namespace app.data
{
    public interface IGenericDataRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IList<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties);
        IList<T> GetList(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties);
        T GetSingle(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties);
        void Add(params T[] items);
        void Update(params T[] items);
        void Remove(params T[] items);
    }

}

namespace app.data
{
    public class GenericDataRepository<T> : IGenericDataRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        public virtual IList<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
        {
            List<T> list;
            using (var context = new GatePassEntities())
                {
                IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

                //Apply eager loading
                foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                    dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

                list = dbQuery
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToList<T>();
            }
            return list;
        }

        public virtual IList<T> GetList(Func<T, bool> where,
             params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
        {
            List<T> list;
            using (var context = new GatePassEntities())
            {
                IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

                //Apply eager loading
                foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                    dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

                list = dbQuery
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(where)
                    .ToList<T>();
            }
            return list;
        }

        public virtual T GetSingle(Func<T, bool> where,
             params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
        {
            T item = null;
            using (var context = new GatePassEntities())
            {
                IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

                //Apply eager loading
                foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                    dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

                item = dbQuery
                    .AsNoTracking() //Don't track any changes for the selected item
                    .FirstOrDefault(where); //Apply where clause
            }
            return item;
        }

        public virtual void Add(params T[] items)
        {
            using (var context = new GatePassEntities())
            {
                foreach (T item in items)
                {
                    context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public virtual void Update(params T[] items)
        {
            using (var context = new GatePassEntities())
            {
                foreach (T item in items)
                {
                    context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public virtual void Remove(params T[] items)
        {
            using (var context = new GatePassEntities())
            {
                foreach (T item in items)
                {
                    context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

    }
}

//Domain Models like Employee, Department can be your objectcontext(Code-first/Model-first), dbcontext(database-first) (can be generated by EF or other ORM Tools like T4)
namespace app.data
{
    public interface IEmployeeRepository : IGenericDataRepository<Employee>
    {
    }

    public interface IDepartmentRepository : IGenericDataRepository<Department>
    {
    }
}

***BUSINESS LAYER***

namespace app.business
{
    public interface IBusinessLayer
    {
        IList<Employee> GetAllEmployees();
        IList<Employee> GetEmployeesByCountryName(string countryName);
        Employee GetEmployeeByName(string EmployeeName);
        Employee GetEmployeeByIdentityId(int identityId, string EmployeeUniqueIdentityNumber);
        void AddEmployee(params Employee[] Employees);
        void UpdateEmployee(params Employee[] Employees);
        void RemoveEmployee(params Employee[] Employees);
    }
}

public class BuinessLayer : IBusinessLayer
{
 private readonly IEmployeeRepository _EmployeeRepository;


        public BuinessLayer()
        {
            _EmployeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository();

        }

        public BuinessLayer(IEmployeeRepository EmployeeRepository)
        {
            _EmployeeRepository = EmployeeRepository;

        }

        public IList<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
        {
            return _EmployeeRepository.GetAll();
        }

        public IList<Employee> GetEmployeesByCountryName(string countryName)
        {
            return _EmployeeRepository.GetList(e => e.Country.Employees.Equals(countryName));
        }

        public Employee GetEmployeeByName(string EmployeeName)
        {
            return _EmployeeRepository.GetSingle(
                d => d.Name.Equals(EmployeeName),
                d => d.Country); //include related employees
        }

        public Employee GetEmployeeByIdentityId(int identityId, string EmployeeUniqueIdentityNumber)
        {
            var EmployeeIdentity = _EmployeeIdentityRepository
                .GetSingle
                (
                q => q.IdentityId == identityId && q.UniqueIdentityNumber == EmployeeUniqueIdentityNumber);
            Employee Employee = new Employee();
            if (EmployeeIdentity != null)
            {
                Employee = _EmployeeRepository.GetSingle(o => o.EmployeeId == EmployeeIdentity.EmployeeId);
            }
            else
                Employee = null;
            return Employee;
        }

        public void AddEmployee(params Employee[] Employees)
        {
            try
            {
                _EmployeeRepository.Add(Employees);
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        public void UpdateEmployee(params Employee[] Employees)
        {
            /* Validation and error handling omitted */
            _EmployeeRepository.Update(Employees);
        }

        public void RemoveEmployee(params Employee[] Employees)
        {
            /* Validation and error handling omitted */
            _EmployeeRepository.Remove(Employees);
        }
}
```